# Why text is pushed towards the top of the circle

Tags: html, css, sass, primeng

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56650765/why-is-the-text-being-pushed-up), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801181/vertically-and-horizontally-centering-text-in-circle-in-css-like-iphone-notific), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615403/css-how-to-draw-circle-with-text-in-middle) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44674206/align-text-in-the-middle-of-a-circle-with-css) question. But the solution is not working because the problem is slightly different. I'm using a calendar component called `<p-calendar>` from `primeng`. It is a `month-picker` actually. This component has already a well defined styling in `primeng.css`. The component by default looks like this:

[image]

But I want to put my styling. I want it be to encircled by blue color on hover. I have achieved this:

[image].

But as you can see month name is pushed towards the top and not in the middle.
Here is **primeng.css** that I'm trying to modify.
**CSS that was already there**

```
.ui-datepicker {
    width: 10px;
    padding: .2em;
    position: absolute;
}

.ui-datepicker.ui-datepicker-inline {
    display: inline-block;
    position: static;
}

.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-group {
    border-left-width: 0;
    border-right-width: 0;
    border-top-width: 0;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
}


/* Month Picker */
    .ui-monthpicker .ui-monthpicker-month {
    width: 33.3%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .5em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-datepicker-monthpicker select.ui-datepicker-year {
    width: auto;
}
```

**CSS that I added later on**

```
.ui-monthpicker-month {
    border-radius: 100% !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #73767b;
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    height: 50px !important;
    width: 50px !important;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.ui-monthpicker-month:hover {
    background-color: #1474A4 !important;
    color: white !important;
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

I'm not very good at styling. Any advice and suggestions will be of great help.

PS: I also tried adding `padding-top: 15px` on `:hover` but then it started flickering.

Comment: Using this `.ui-monthpicker .ui-monthpicker-month {
    width: 33.3%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 36px 30px !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 100% !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
}` is good enough I think.

Comment: @little_coder. I appreciate your help but its not working.Still have some issues. Nnow it is pushed to the right and the circle is somewhat oval in shape now.

Comment: I think it depend on the size of the screen. When I resize my screen it does have some issue.

Comment: @Tanzel can you try this css hack if working on your side? `.ui-monthpicker-month {
    color: #333333;
    border-radius: 100% !important;
    height: 0  !important; padding-top: 13%  !important;
    padding-bottom: 20%  !important;
}`

Comment: It is working well on my side. Tried PC, tablet and mobile.

Comment: @little_coder Then i think because of my hard coding the padding and margins it is giving me problems.

Comment: @little_coder. Post this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do a trick using percentage on the padding top and bottom and set the height element to zero.

```
.ui-monthpicker-month { 
   color: #333333; 
   border-radius: 100% !important;
   height: 0 !important;
   padding-top: 13% !important;
   padding-bottom: 20% !important; 
}

.ui-monthpicker-month:hover {
    background-color: #1474A4 !important;
    color: #fff;
}
```

And here is the screenshots:

------------------------------ PC ------------------------------

[image: PC]

------------------------------ Tablet ------------------------------

[image: Tablet]

------------------------------ Phone ------------------------------

[image: Phone]

Answer (score 1):

Just add line-height as you need.

I added `2em` you can change as required.

```css
.ui-monthpicker .ui-monthpicker-month {
    background-color:#3399cc;
    width: 33.3%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height:2em; // <-- Add line height
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-monthpicker">
   <div class="ui-monthpicker-month">Jan</div>
   <div class="ui-monthpicker-month">Feb</div> 
</div>
```